# Unable to use reverse proxy nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have two node js apps that I want to put behind nginx.
I access application 1 which has "/" as a base and I access its pages which are on /be/ but when I try to go to application 2 automatically I am referred to "/".

summary

App1:
based:"/"
url: localhost:3003
application pages can be found in /be/

App2:
base:"/be/"
url: localhost:3000/be/login
the application pages can also be found on /be/

here is my nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.1.64;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/portalerr.logs;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/portalaccess.logs;

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.64:3003/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    }

    location /login/ {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.64:3000/be/login;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    rewrite /be/login(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

}

Comment: very cool didn't know that you could set headers when reversing proxy